# Where can I find previous ACM ICPC contest problems?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm leading a small group of developer at my university and I'd like to work through a couple of ICPC problem sets from previous years.

Searching on Google yields no useful results, just page upon page of broken links and private .edu domains.

Does anyone know where to find these problem sets from previous years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the motherload here:

http://livearchive.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8

Answer (score 1):

You might also like the following problems:

Google has posted some interesting problems. People also post their solutions, so you can see how others implemented a solution. 
http://code.google.com/codejam/contests.html

Reddit is also another good source to get interesting problems. 
http://www.reddit.com/r/programmingchallenges/